# How to get comman data from two list of dictionaries based on having comman values for a specific key in both list's dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

First list of dictionaries:

```
ldic_1 = [{'personId': '2DHSJ32N2'}, {'personId': '8SHFJW7BA'}, {'personId': '2KS4BA0X9'}, {'personId': '2H84XKNH1'}, {'personId': '2H7QW2J4S'}, {'personId': '2HAY258CG'}]
```

Second list of dictionaries:

```
ldic_2 = [{'id': '2DHSJ32N2', 'fname': 'Adam'}, {'id': '8SHFJW7BA', 'fname': 'Smith'}, {'id': '2KS4BA0X9', 'fname': 'Lara'}, {'id': '2H7QW2J4S', 'fname': 'Kane'}, {'id': '2H84XKNH1', 'fname': 'Donald'}, {'id': '2H86CEQDG', 'fname': 'Nastya'}, {'id': '2H95F5D81', 'fname': 'Karolina'}, {'id': '2HA7GUKPQ', 'fname': 'Sara'}, {'id': '2H7TPXZSN', 'fname': 'Harry'}, {'id': '2HARDNGSW', 'fname': 'Joe'}, {'id': '2HAS95FR5', 'fname': 'Jill'}, {'id': '2HAY258CG', 'fname': 'David'}]
```

Whenever the value of "personId" of ldic_1 matches with the value of "id" of ldic_2 then the ldic_2 will get updated and the expected result will be:

```
ldic_2 = [{'id': '2DHSJ32N2', 'fname': 'Adam'}, {'id': '8SHFJW7BA', 'fname': 'Smith'}, {'id': '2KS4BA0X9', 'fname': 'Lara'}, , {'id': '2H7QW2J4S', 'fname': 'Kane'}, {'id': '2H84XKNH1', 'fname': 'Donald'}, {'id': '2HAY258CG', 'fname': 'David'}]
```

I don't know how to do this. Please help and thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Simply iterate through the first dictionary and check if the ```personId``` is in ```ldic_2```.  If it isn't in it,  remove that item.

Comment: @ewong I am new in Python so please specify the steps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an effective way of solving this (assuming that `id` is unique):

```
ldic_1 = [{'personId': '2DHSJ32N2'}, {'personId': '8SHFJW7BA'}, {'personId': '2KS4BA0X9'}, {'personId': '2H84XKNH1'},
          {'personId': '2H7QW2J4S'}, {'personId': '2HAY258CG'}]

ldic_2 = [{'id': '2DHSJ32N2', 'fname': 'Adam'}, {'id': '8SHFJW7BA', 'fname': 'Smith'},
          {'id': '2KS4BA0X9', 'fname': 'Lara'}, {'id': '2H8C3J8VD', 'fname': 'Kane'},
          {'id': '2H84XKNH1', 'fname': 'Donald'}, {'id': '2H86CEQDG', 'fname': 'Nastya'},
          {'id': '2H95F5D81', 'fname': 'Karolina'}, {'id': '2HA7GUKPQ', 'fname': 'Sara'},
          {'id': '2H7TPXZSN', 'fname': 'Harry'}, {'id': '2HARDNGSW', 'fname': 'Joe'},
          {'id': '2HAS95FR5', 'fname': 'Jill'}, {'id': '2HAY258CG', 'fname': 'David'}]

adict = {elem['id']: elem for elem in ldic_2}

result = []
for elem in ldic_1:
    if elem['personId'] in adict:
        result.append(adict[elem['personId']])

# if you want one-liner:
# result = [adict[elem['personId']] for elem in ldic_1 if elem['personId'] in adict]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': '2DHSJ32N2', 'fname': 'Adam'}, {'id': '8SHFJW7BA', 'fname': 'Smith'}, {'id': '2KS4BA0X9', 'fname': 'Lara'}, {'id': '2H84XKNH1', 'fname': 'Donald'}, {'id': '2HAY258CG', 'fname': 'David'}]
```

Comment: Can list comprehensions be used instead of nested for loop?

Comment: yes, see comment,  I posted one liner there: result = [{'id': elem['personId']} for elem in ldic_1 if elem['personId'] in adict]

Comment: By mistake i have added wrong result. Can you please take a look on the question again? Thanks

Comment: @Learner  Updated, but why there's Kane in the result?

Comment: Kane is there in result because Kane's id is matching with the personId in ldic_1. By the way i have solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: @Learner if my answer helped feel free to approve it

Comment: @Learner you can click the "Approve" button

Answer (score 0):

```
set_of_ids = {dic['personId'] for dic in ldic_1} 
for dic in ldic_2:
    if dic['id'] in set_of_ids:
        del dic['fname']
```

Output :

```
[{'id': '2DHSJ32N2'},
 {'id': '8SHFJW7BA'},
 {'id': '2KS4BA0X9'},
 {'id': '2H8C3J8VD', 'fname': 'Kane'},
 {'id': '2H84XKNH1'},
 {'id': '2H86CEQDG', 'fname': 'Nastya'},
 {'id': '2H95F5D81', 'fname': 'Karolina'},
 {'id': '2HA7GUKPQ', 'fname': 'Sara'},
 {'id': '2H7TPXZSN', 'fname': 'Harry'},
 {'id': '2HARDNGSW', 'fname': 'Joe'},
 {'id': '2HAS95FR5', 'fname': 'Jill'},
 {'id': '2HAY258CG'}]
```